# Can't use jdbc inside clojure

Tags: sql, clojure

I am trying to make connect clojure to mysql, but somehow fail.
My project.clj is:

```
(defproject my-project "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
  :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]
                 [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.2.3"]]
  :jvm-opts ["-Djdbc.drivers=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"])
```

My file is:

```
(ns my-project
  (:require [clojure.java.jdbc :as sql]))


(def db {:classname "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
         :subprotocol "mysql"
         :subname "//localhost:3306/db"
         :user "xxx"
         :password "xxx"})
```

And I am trying to run the following from the REPL:

```
(sql/with-connection db (sql/with-query-results rows "show tables;"))
```

The error I am getting is:

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db
```

I have in sql a database called db and I ensured mysql.server is running on port 3306.
I would be grateful if someone could give me a hint.
Also my error message is not dependant from the username and password I provide, and nothing is shown on the log file from mysql.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You still fail to put the driver in the classpath. The `org.clojure/java.jdbc` only provides the client libraries, not the driver itself. Add the following to your `:dependencies`:

```
[mysql/mysql-connector-java "5.1.18"]
```